# Two NSTableViews in a single view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I have two NSTableViews in a same view and they have the same data source and delegate.

The two table views are named as varTableView and constraintTableView. Now the number of rows in each is different and I I am finding it difficult to implement the two methods:

`-(NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView`
`-(id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`

Is there any way to identify the tableviews and return the corresponding number of rows?

My implementation was something like this:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    if([tableView.identifier isEqualToString:@"variableTableView"]){
        return [self.arrayOfVariableNames count];

    }
    else{
        return [self.arrayOfConstraintNames count];
    }
}
```

it is always returning the count of constraints names but not the variable names

Comment: Did you actually set the identifier of `variableTableView` to "variableTableView"? You're better off simply comparing the pointer values of the table view references.

Comment: Yes. I set it up in the restoration ID

Comment: Don't know what you mean by restoration ID. There's a property on `NSControl` (of which `NSTableView` is a subclass) called `identifier`. *That's* what you need to set, if you're going to take this approach.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I used tags and it is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can implement this either by using name of table or tag of table to know for which table particular delegate method is called for like

```
   -(NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView -(id) tableView:  (NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:   (NSInteger)row
   {
         if (tableView == varTableView)// or check table tag, first you need to set tag for table
         {
           // do something with varTableView
           return ([array1 count]);

        }
       else if (tableView == constraintTableView)
       {
        // do something with constraintTableView
          return ([array2 count]);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I was trying to do this using the identifier method. it is not working though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's the `tableView` parameter in the methods you included.

```
if (tableView == varTableView)
{
    // do something with varTableView
}
else if (tableView == constraintTableView)
{
    // do something with constraintTableView
}
```

The number of rows tends to be the number of objects in the array serving as the data source.

Comment: Aw, bless your heart; I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in other answers you can differentiate between two tables by comparing its outlets. There s also another way but you would have to change your existing designs a bit.

Instead of adding two table views in one view controller, create a placeholder view for both of them. Create two table view controllers and add them to these placeholder views as subviews. This way you can have both tables in separate controllers and it will get rid of all the if else blocks which you will end up writing. It might slow you down initially but you will get benefitted later.